# WebPack: Dynamic File Paths and the dreaded "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression"

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I have the following code which WebPack is very unhappy about giving the error message "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression":

```
for(let x=0; x<entries.length;x++){
    const entry = entries[x];
    const folder = util.getSafeFolder(__dirname, entry.type);
    const input = require(file);
    this.#inputSources[entry.type + "." + entry.subtype] = (new input());
}
```

This is a correct error, as I am dynamically loading a resource with the require(file).

What I'm wondering is how I tell WebPack, "Hey, I want you to consider ALL the JS/TS files in the following directories as possibilities for that expression"; and thereby be sure everything is loaded so that warning is not an issue (or the warning goes away).

In researching this I stumbled across the [ContextReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/context-replacement-plugin/). Based on its name I feel like it should solve my problem, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it for this use case.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is my current webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin");
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
        fallback: {
            "fs": false,
            "tls": false,
            "net": false,
            "dns": false,
            "child_process": false
        }
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'lib.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin(),
        //new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```